# can't get select query to work

Tags: mysql, c, arrays, select

I want to use a Select query from mysql database in C:

```
mysql_query(conn,"SELECT SI AS SUBSCRIBER_ID ,TG2 AS TAG_ID, SUM(CTR) AS NBR FROM (SELECT H.SUBSCRIBER_ID AS SI, TG.TAG_ID AS TG1,T.TAG_ID AS TG2, COUNT(TG.TAG_ID) AS COUNTER,CASE WHEN (TG.TAG_ID = T.TAG_ID) THEN COUNT(TG.TAG_ID) ELSE 0 END AS CTR from content_hits H left join  CONTENT_TAG TG ON TG.CONTENT_ID = H.CONTENT_ID LEFT JOIN TAG T ON 1= 1 GROUP BY H.SUBSCRIBER_ID, TG.TAG_ID,T.TAG_ID) AS TAB GROUP BY SI,TG2");
```

After that, I want to use 'NBR' to fill an array of one dimension.

I tried this:

```
result = mysql_store_result(conn);

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
  t[i]=*row['NBR'];
  printf("%d",t[i]);
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @holy how does it not work?  Are there error messages?  Unexpected results?  Please be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the query, and perhaps the table's schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the row columns by name like you have  `t[i]=*row['NBR'];`. Use for example `fields = mysql_fetch_fields(result);` to get the column names and iterate through the fields array to find which column id 'NBR' has. This id can then be used in `t[i]=row[id];`. This is all in the mysql connectors doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-fields.html